# bExpress bodyparser not configuing properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a server.js file, where i have a `trainer route`

which is used for creating some routes in express, but whenever i run the program, it gives me a typeError

```
firstName: req.body.firstName,                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
```

here is my entire server.js file. I have configured the correct bodyparsers for express, yet it still gives me the same error

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const properties = require('./config/properties');
const db = require('./config/database');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const log = require('morgan')('dev');
const cors = require('cors');


// call the database connectivity function
db();




//configure middleware
app.use(log);
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


//parsers
const router = express.Router();

//routes
const trainerRoutes = require('./api/trainers/trainer.routes');



//configure routes
app.use('/api', router);

trainerRoutes(router);


app.listen(properties.PORT, (req, res)=>{
    console.log(`Server running on ${properties.PORT} port`)
});
```

why does this problem occur?

EDIT:

here is the function in which the error occurs, this is in the trainer.controller.js file:

```
exports.updateTrainer = function(req, res, next) {
    const trainer = {
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        biography: req.body.description,
        certificates: req.body.certificates
    };
    Trainer.update({_id: req.params.id}, trainer, function(err, trainer) {
        if(err) {
            res.json({
                error : err
                //should make a log message here
            })
        }
        res.json({
            message : "Trainer updated successfully"
        })
    })
};
```

trainer.routes.js file

```
module.exports = function(router) {
    router.post('/create', Trainer.createTrainer);
    router.get('/get', Trainer.getAllTrainers);
    router.get('/get/:name', Trainer.getTrainer);
    router.put('/update/:id', Trainer.updateTrainer());
    router.delete('/remove/:id', Trainer.removeHero());
};
```

Comment: Can you provide the code sections where the error has occurred?

Comment: The error means that `req` is undefined. Can you show the trainer route code?

Comment: Can you add trainerRoutes code to the question?

Comment: i Have edited the code

Comment: The error suggests that `updateTrainer()` is not called by express but through some other mechanism, one that doesn't properly pass along the Request object as first parameter. Can you post `trainer.routes.js`?

Comment: There's the problem: `router.put('/update/:id', Trainer.updateTrainer());` remove the `()` after `updateTrainer` You wanted to pass the function, you've passed its return value instead, which is `undefined`. In addition you called the function without arguments, which caused the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this line

```
app.use('/api', router);
```

should be

```
app.use('/api', trainerRoutes);
```

And this line needs to be removed:

```
trainerRoutes(router);
```

And your trainer.routes.js should be like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/create', Trainer.createTrainer);
router.get('/get', Trainer.getAllTrainers);
router.get('/get/:name', Trainer.getTrainer);
router.put('/update/:id', Trainer.updateTrainer);
router.delete('/remove/:id', Trainer.removeHero);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: So without the express router?

Comment: I was about to suggest this but it really all depends on what exactly `trainerRoutes()` does.

Comment: @baileyhaldwin  I also changed the trainer.routes.js code,  can you try with all these changes and say the result?

Comment: You missed the actual problem, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58499857/bexpress-bodyparser-not-configuing-properly#comment103329048_58499857)

Comment: @ChrisG yess that was also problem, I am editing the answer, but if you want I can remove the answer, so that you can post your asnwer?

Comment: This is basically a typo; I've already marked the question as such. No need to answer it.

Comment: Yes thank you for pointing out, but the first part of the your answer should remain i believe, since it is taking in a router as an argument to the function

Comment: @baileyhaldwin This answer just shows a different way of telling express which routes to use. I haven't tested it but as far as I can tell, if you remove the offending two `()` in your original code, everything should work fine.